# Boost socket not throwing EOF on disconnection

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I am writing a simple download service for one of my project in C++ using Boost libraries. What I want is while downloading if my connection breaks, I should stop download. I have read different places that when connection is broken socket returns EOF error, Boost sockets does the same. But my problem is, when the connection is broken boost socket does not throw EOF, instead it just keep on connected, and once connection is back it resumes the download where it stopped. I don't want to resume, I want to quit, so that I will do my own resuming. Question is when the connection is broken why boost socket is not throwing EOF error. Following is my sample code. I have also tried it with asynchronous implementation, I have also tried it with socket.read_some function but same behavior.

```
std::string responseString = "";

try {
    // === Send HTTP Request to get Proxy End Point
    std::string apiPath = "/qtproject/archive/qt/4.0/" + filename;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Get a list of endpoints corrosponding to the server name
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(serverip, serverport);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // Try each endpoint untill we successfully establish a connection.
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "GET " << apiPath << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    request_stream << "Host: " << serverip << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    // Send the request
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    // === Read Server Response
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/") {
        std::cout << " Bad Server Response " << std::endl;
    }
    if (status_code != 200) {
        std::cout << "Bad Status Code = " << status_code << std::endl;
    }
    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    //boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");
    //boost::system::error_code error; //boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof data)
    unsigned char data[1024];
    socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)), error);

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r");

    ofstream image;
    std::string filepath = "/home/farshad/TBD/" + filename;
    image.open(filepath.c_str());

    // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
    int downloadedSize = 0;
    int readSize = 0;
    while ( (readSize = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)), error)) )
    {
            // When the connection is broken it keeps in this while loop, 
            // where I am expecting it to throw EOF error. Once connection is back, 
            // it resumes from the same while loop.
        downloadedSize += readSize;
        std::cout << "Data Read = " << downloadedSize <<  " Bytes\n";
        //memset(data, 0x0, sizeof(data));
        //image << &response;
        //std::cout << "Downloaded = " << (downloadedSize) << " Bytes\n";
    }

    //std::cout << "File Size = " << image.gcount() << std::endl;
    image.close();
    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
      throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    else if ( error == boost::asio::error::eof  ) {
        std::cout << "End of file approached";
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }
}
catch ( std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch ( ... )
{
    std::cout << "HURRAY: We got error" << std::endl;
}
```

**UPDATE**
The disconnection is of nature that someone pulls out the cable, or internet connection disconnection due to ISP.

Comment: You do not check if you actually *have* an error, you will throw a `system_error` anyway.

Comment: By the way, if you want to talk to web-servers in C++ you might want to check out [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/). Using it will simplify your code quite a lot.

Comment: I can not use cpp-netlib now since this boost code is way too deep in my project, it is now when I have encountered a bug for which I am looking into it.

Comment: See [this thread](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/07/50237.php).

Comment: What you are describing as "disconnection" is not a disconnection at a TCP socket level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** Works as designed. HTTP needs a timeout at application lever.

Connection is broken when a packet times out. The fact that the cable was disconnected *cannot be detected* until transmission is attempted. If the network is disconnected but connected again before next transmission attempt, the connection does not break, because it worked for all transmissions and there was no reason to consider it broken.

When there *is* a transmission and the network is disconnected, it still might take several minutes for the connection to break because the timeouts are rather generous since the network does not promise any specific performance. So if you disconnect the cable, but then connect it again before the server times out, the transfer will continue. Because the fault was transient and TCP was designed to deal with those. It has to, because packets occasionally get lost even when everything is operating fine.

That still only applies to the *transmitting* end. The receiving end will not detect that the connection is broken. When you disconnect the network *and keep it disconnected*, the server will, possibly after several minutes, conclude that the connection is broken. But it can't tell the client and the client is not transmitting so it can't find itself. Therefore the client will keep sitting there waiting for data *forever*. It will not receive any more data because the server gave up, but it will not find out unless it tries to write, which it does not.

Therefore you **have to have timer** and if you receive no more data in some time (usual timeouts are on order of 5-10 minutes), you have to close the connection and declare error yourself. The timer should be reset with each received block since the transfer can potentially take longer than the timeout.

Note that not a single dot of the above says anything about boost. These are properties of TCP/IP and the behaviour will be the same with any interface to it and any implementation of it. Also note, that TCP/IP has a "keepalive" option that causes the system (automatically, without further intervention from you) periodically send empty packets to check that the connection is not broken and with that option you will receive eof on read. That option *is not appropriate for HTTP* however. It is usually used for protocols that are kept connected for extended time and may see no traffic for long times like imap or ssh, but for HTTP a receive timeout is the preferred solution.